# Why Gio.Settings do not affect

Tags: python

I want to set up user environment by using Python.
But i can't understand why this code does not work?

Environment:

Ubuntu  18.04.1
Python 2.7.15rc1
python-gi 3.26.1-2
libgtk-3-0: 3.22.30-1ubu

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gio

gsettings = Gio.Settings.new('org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock')
gsettings.set_int('dash-max-icon-size', 16)
gsettings.apply()
```

and execute this code like `sudo python /home/username/Documents/setup.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code started work when i removed `sudo` from command line. So I running this code just like `python /home/username/Documents/setup.py` Now works as expected! But why?

... and code works without `gsettings.apply()` so I commented this line

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, your objective is to setup ***your** user* environment. When you run your code with [`sudo` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo), you're running it as the *superuser*, so you're actually changing ***root***'s environment!

As for why `.apply()` is not needed: When you instance a setting using `Gio.Settings.new()`, like you did, changes are applied *immediately*. From the [official documentation on `.apply()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/Settings.html#Gio.Settings.apply):

> Applies any changes that have been made to the settings. This function does nothing unless self is in ‘delay-apply’ mode; see Gio.Settings.delay(). In the normal case settings are always applied immediately